# OmniAuth invalid_response with Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

Using OmniAuth, Rails 3.1.0.rc2, mysql2, ruby 1.9.2.p0.

I still get this when redirecting back to my site.

```
/auth/failure?message=invalid_response
```

Omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'XXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

I've checked the keys 100x and they are correct. Still getting the invalid response. Any of the questions I see don't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks. [:

If any new information is needed, just ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are not putting the keys in the wrong order?

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, TW_CONSUMER_KEY, TW_CONSUMER_SECRET
end
```

If not, let's quickly test your credentials with the Twitter gem:

```
# twitter.rb -- Test credentials

require "rubygems"
require "twitter"

# Get a user's most recent status update
puts Twitter.user_timeline("YOUR_USER").first.text

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = TW_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = TW_CONSUMER_SECRET
end

# Update your status
Twitter.update("I Love ruby!")
```

If it works, then your credentials are fine... you should keep looking into Rails...

Comment: Getting 'Twitter::Unauthorized: POST https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json: 401: Could not authenticate you.'

The consumer_key and consumer_secret are 100% correct, though. It's a bit aggravating.

Comment: Well, it seems the problem is with the authentication. Maybe you can try to register a different application and get a different pair of keys.

Comment: This quick way to test Twitter OAuth credentials doesn't seem to work for me on known, good credentials that work in a small app I wrote. Is this still an accurate way of testing with the latest releases of the gems used here? I too am running into an OmniAuth problem when I've had it working fine on a previous app and even repeated resetting of the credentials doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

If you use this `request.env['rack.auth']` in your controller, change this to `request.env['omniauth.auth']` - this were explained here [OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)

this solution works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.  It turns out that I actually had some runtime errors in my Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter method:

I was calling a method on a non-existent method on a nil object and this was raising an exception, but either devise or omniauth were swallowing the exception.

I ended up wrapping my entire method body in a begin/rescue clause and printing out the exception.

However, if you are getting Invalid Credentials then it's likely that the twitter-issued oauth key has expired and so your user should really be calling /users/auth/twitter again.

Comment: I can confirm that oauth eats exceptions. :-(  You'd think there'd be a way to let most types pass through, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Christian for your answer. It was very helpful for me. But if it gives a 401 error trying to update, retweet, etc you will have to include

```
  config.oauth_token = 'MY_OAUTH_TOKEN'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'MY_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET'
```

to Twitter client configuration. Look at https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1522

So finally you will have

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'TW_CONSUMER_KEY'
  config.consumer_secret = 'TW_CONSUMER_SECRET'
  config.oauth_token = 'MY_OAUTH_TOKEN'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'MY_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET'   
end
```

It worked for me

and of course your Twitter app has to have Access level = Read and write. You have to change this in dev.twitter.com if you want to update the status, retweet, etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried omniauth-twitter gem?? https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter